# Dependency file like css, javascript are not working in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, layout, include, laravel-5

I have all my CSS and JavaScript files in public a folder. I am using Laravel 5.

My view layout:

```
- public
  -  css
  - fonts
  - images
  - js

- layouts
  -  head.blade.php
  -  header.blade.php
  - footer.blade.php

- adverts
  - index.blade.php
  - advertiserShow.blade.php
```

My Controller

```
public function show($advert){


    $adverts = Adverts::all()->where('ad_advertiser', $advert);
    return view('adverts.advertiserShow', compact('adverts'));
}
```

My Route

```
Route::resource('adverts','AdvertsController');
```

My index.blade.php working fine with all css and javascript file. but not in advertiserShow.blade.php

Just wondering Is this is the right way. what might be the error one is working not another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap all assets within [asset](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-asset) helper function. Also you can see [free lesson](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/19) how to manage assets in Laravel.

Comment: The video links give answers to all problems. Wow Technology go great.. Thanks @Kinil. I will start implementing.